# Is it possible to Google/web search based on SITE TITLE alone?

Tags: web, metadata, google-search, search-engines

Say someone knows the title a site uses on one of its possibly indexed pages.

Given so, is it possible to search ONLY FOR TITLES OF WEBPAGES PRIMARILY, as opposed to overall results?

Title as in the HTML meta data title.

You know, the part that appears where the hyperlink is? Can one search this way? Why or why not? It just came to my mind that this sounds like it could be possible in theory at least.

Answer (score 1):

Use the prefix `allintitle:` or `intitle:` before your search criteria.

For example: enter `allintitle: Google useful prefix` will cause the search engine to look for the words entered (Google, useful and prefix) in the titles of webpages only.  All words entered must be present.

The shorter `intitle:` will not require *all* terms to be in the title, but will only look at the title.